# Kubernetes Pod Operator is unable to fetch AWS S3 credentials during run time

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-s3, airflow

I've an Airflow DAG which uses a kubernetes pod operator for running a java application using docker image. The Java application fetches data from an S3 bucket. I pass the AWS endpoint and url as part of env variables and IAM role as part of annotations.

The code works fine at times but sometimes it fails with an error that could not find AWS credentials. I could not find any pattern in the error, just fails randomly.